# configure error when installing apache on ubuntu

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

it says configure error: C compiler cannnot create executables
what is the problem?

Comment: Could you add some more info on how you tried to install apache ? What are the exact commands you used ?

Comment: ./configure /*and nothing more*/

Comment: I guess this matters http://www.electrictoolbox.com/c-compiler-cannot-create-executables/

Comment: Any particular you don't simply install the pre built package from the Ubuntu repositories?

Answer (score 2):

It appears you do not have gcc/cc installed, or you have an alternative compiler without the ability to generate a binary for your platform.

Answer (score 0):

The simple fix is:

aptitude install build-essential

To get a basic build environment.

However there's pretty much *no* reason to build your own apache on a Debian based system (such as Ubuntu). If there's something that the Ubuntu apache doesn't do (or the other modules available in the repositories) you should open a bug and get it fixed.

Comment: While it's basically the right procedure to file a bug report for missing features, you sometimes just need these features *right now* and can't wait for another release of the distribution or you have quite exotic requirements which will never be integrated with the mainstream packages of your distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Does it also say:

```
See `config.log' for more details
```

You should probably look in config.log for details.